TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') in nextjs and Auth.js
I am using the credentials provider with Auth.js and next.js framework, and my auth.ts file looks like this:
import { Client } from 'ldapts';
import NextAuth, { type DefaultSession, type User } from 'next-auth';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import z from 'zod';

const CredentialsSchema = z.object({
  username: z.string().regex(/^\d+$/, 'Username must contain only digits'),
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(6, 'Password must contain at least 6 characters long'),
});

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      username: string;
      displayName: string;
      memberOf: string[];
    } & DefaultSession['user'];
  }

  interface User {
    username: string;
    displayName: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[];
    memberOf: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[];
    mail: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[];
  }
}

export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: 'LDAP',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username/DN', type: 'text', placeholder: '' },
        displayName: {},
        memberOf: {},
        mail: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        const result = CredentialsSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (!result.success) {
          console.log(result.error.errors);
          return null;
        }

        const { username, password } = result.data;
        const ldapUrl =
          process.env.LDAP_URI || 'ldaps://server.com.es:3269';
        const client = new Client({
          url: ldapUrl,
        });

        try {
          await client.bind(
            `CN=${username}`,
            password,
          );
          const extraInfo = await client.search(
            `CN=${username},DC=InfoDir,DC=Prod`,
            { attributes: ['cn', 'dn', 'displayName', 'memberOf', 'mail'] }, 
          );

          const { cn, dn, displayName, memberOf, mail } =
            extraInfo?.searchEntries?.[0] || {};

          const user: User = {
            username: username,
            displayName: displayName,
            memberOf: memberOf,
            mail: mail,
          };
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('LDAP failed', error);
          return null;
        } finally {
          await client.unbind();
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.username = user.username;
        token.displayName = user.displayName;
        token.memberOf = user.memberOf;
        token.email = user.email;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          username: user.username,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          memberOf: user.memberOf,
        },
      };
    },
  },
});

However, I am facing some problems when authenticating. The authentication proceeds, but I get an error on the server as follows:
[auth][error] JWTSessionError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#jwtsessionerror
[auth][cause]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
    at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./auth.ts:90:36)
    at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@5.0.0-beta.21_next@15.0.0-canary.141_@babel+core@7.25.2_react-dom@19.0.0-rc-d1afcb4_bc4ujvd5qqpx2azyxej2iwuvze/node_modules/next-auth/lib/index.js:33:51)
    at Module.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.35.0/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/actions/session.js:41:52)
    at async AuthInternal (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.35.0/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/index.js:47:24)
    at async Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.35.0/node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:127:34)
    at async Page (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/dashboard/inventory/page.tsx:52:21)
[auth][details]: {}
undefined

PS: After substituting to token i got this:
Type '({ session, token }: { session: { user: AdapterUser; } & AdapterSession; user: AdapterUser; } & { session: Session; token: JWT; } & { newSession: any; trigger?: "update" | undefined; }) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(params: { session: { user: AdapterUser; } & AdapterSession; user: AdapterUser; } & { session: Session; token: JWT; } & { newSession: any; trigger?: "update" | undefined; }) => Awaitable<...>'.
Type 'Promise<{ user: { username: unknown; displayName: unknown; memberOf: unknown; email: unknown; id: string; emailVerified: Date | null; name?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; mail: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]; }; sessionToken: string; userId: string; expires: Date & string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<Session | DefaultSession>'.
Type 'Promise<{ user: { username: unknown; displayName: unknown; memberOf: unknown; email: unknown; id: string; emailVerified: Date | null; name?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; mail: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]; }; sessionToken: string; userId: string; expires: Date & string; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<Session | DefaultSession>'.
Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
Type '<TResult1 = { user: { username: unknown; displayName: unknown; memberOf: unknown; email: unknown; id: string; emailVerified: Date | null; name?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; mail: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]; }; sessionToken: string; userId: string; expires: Date & string; ...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = Session | DefaultSession, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Session | DefaultSession) => TResult1 | PromiseLike) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type '{ user: { username: unknown; displayName: unknown; memberOf: unknown; email: unknown; id: string; emailVerified: Date | null; name?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; mail: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]; }; sessionToken: string; userId: string; expires: Date & string; }' is not assignable to type 'Session | DefaultSession'.
Type '{ user: { username: unknown; displayName: unknown; memberOf: unknown; email: unknown; id: string; emailVerified: Date | null; name?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; mail: string | string[] | Buffer | Buffer[]; }; sessionToken: string; userId: string; expires: Date & string; }' is not assignable to type 'DefaultSession'.
The types of 'user.email' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.ts(2322)

You seem to be accessing the username property from the user parameter in your session callback, yet your sessions are handled via JWT (even if your authentication uses and LDAP server). Per the documentation:
When using database sessions, the User (user) object is passed as an argument.
When using JSON Web Tokens for sessions, the JWT payload (token) is provided instead.
In fact, in your jwt callback you are already assigning the user values into your token property. You just need to change your session callback to:
async session({ session, token, user }) {
  return {
    ...session,
    user: {
      ...session.user,
      username: token.username as string,
      displayName: token.displayName as string,
      memberOf: token.memberOf as string,
    },
  };
}

Note the casting to prevent the second error you faced which seemed to be due to the fact that the values inside token are resolving to unknown.
